# How does this authentication (condition) work?

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement

```
$user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
        if (!$user || !Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
            return response([
                'message' => ['Credenitials do no match']],404);
        }
```

Can someone make me understand the if block ?

Comment: It simply checks whether the a user with the input email address exists ```!$user``` and if the input password doesn't match the password in the database ```!Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)```. If the user doesn't exist or the passwords do not match then it sends a 404 response saying the credentials are wrong

Comment: the Hash::check use to check the given plain value against a hash.

Comment: There's a lot of things to break down in that single if statement. Any particular part you're having difficulty understanding or is it every single part of it?

Answer (score 1):

First, it tries to find the user via the email passed in the http request:

```
$user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
```

Then it checks if the user exists and if the already hashed version of the password stored in the database matches the (hashed) password passed with the request:

```
if (!$user || !Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
```

If it doesn't, then it returns a response with 404 status and a message:

```
'message' => ['Credenitials do no match']],404);
```

If the password matches, then the code continues.

Comment: and please don't forget to accept the answer if it answers your question :)